# How create a type for classes (not instances) extending a base class?

Tags: typescript

Please see question title and pseudo code of what I want below. How replace the *any*? Preferably not by making some huge manual union type.

```
    abstract class Letter {}
    
    class A extends Letter {}
    class B extends Letter {}
    class C extends Letter {}
    // potentially hundreds more "letters"

    type LetterClass = any
    
    const exampleUsage: LetterClass[] = [A, B, C]
```

#### attempting with typeof

```
type LetterClass = typeof Letter
const letters: LetterClass[] = [A, B, C]
const sample = letters[0]
new sample() // Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.
```

Comment: Could you share what you need this for? Depending on your use case, it may be better to make an array of constructors instead.

Comment: I have a factory class which holds a name/alias-to-class map to let the factory reach for sub factories and then instanciate them

Comment: Great, so if all you need is to instantiate the classes, I think you could only store the constructors of those types rather than the classes themselves. It'd be much easier that way, something like `letters: (() => Letter)[] = [() => new A(), ...]` (I don't know TS, but you get my point)

Comment: Id prefer not to keep a list of pre instanciated classes, but rather instanciate when there is an actual need for one of the sub classes. When doing that I would like to type the list of sub classes properly

Comment: `() => new A()` would create a new object each time, it's not instantiated before it's called. If you really still want the type, you could keep tuples containing both the type and constructor.

Comment: Not following 100% can you show that in an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238254/discussion-between-user-and-ajthinking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a type like this: `{new(): Letter}`. Full example:

```
abstract class Letter {}
    
class A extends Letter {}
class B extends Letter {}
class C extends Letter {}
// potentially hundreds more "letters"

type LetterClass = {new(): Letter}

const letters: LetterClass[] = [A, B, C]
const sample = letters[0]
new sample()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `typeof` keyword in typescript to create a type for your classes.

```js
type LetterClass = typeof Letter;
```

Comment: Please see updated question what happens. Thanks!